# Tabindex does not restored in IE

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer, tabindex

I have the following markup: http://jsfiddle.net/79zv0Lmt/2/

```
tabindex="102"
<input type="text" name="name" value=" " tabindex="102" />
<br />

tabindex="103"
<input id="t2" type="text" name="name" value=" " tabindex="103" />
<br />

tabindex="104"                                    
<input type="text" name="name" value=" " tabindex="104" />
<br />

tabindex="101"                                    
<input id="first" type="text" name="name" value=" " tabindex="101" />
```

I change tabindex of "t2" input to "-1" and then to "103". It works as expected in all browsers except IE. In IE it works as if tabindex="-1". How can i fix this for IE?

Comment: Successfully reproduced the problem in IE11(KB2976627).

Comment: More simple example: [http://jsfiddle.net/79zv0Lmt/5/](http://jsfiddle.net/79zv0Lmt/5/)